How to prove the convexity/concavity of the following inverse function?
Consider the function $$z(v,\mathbf{Q})=f(v,\mathbf{Q})=\mathrm{tr}\left\{(\mathbf{Q}+v^{-1}\mathbf{I})^{-1}\right\},$$ where $v$ is a positive scalar variable, while $\mathbf{Q}$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix variable.
I want to see whether the inverse function $$v(z,\mathbf{Q})=f^{-1}(z,\mathbf{Q})$$ is ${\it{operator}}$ convex or ${\it{operator}}$ concave or neither ${\it{operator}}$ convex nor ${\it{operator}}$ concave w.r.t the matrix $\mathbf{Q}$, but I can't write an analytic expression for this function, so is there any way to show the convexity/concavity of this function?
I just looked up the more specialized terminology, what I meant was to find if this function is operator convex or operator concave w.r.t the matrix $\mathbf{Q}$, e.g. if
$$
\alpha f^{-1}(z,\mathbf{Q}_1)+(1-\alpha)f^{-1}(z,\mathbf{Q}_2)\geq f^{-1}(z,\alpha \mathbf{Q}_1+(1-\alpha)\mathbf{Q}_2)
$$
it is operator convex, conversely, it is operator concave.

The trace is linear, thus $tr(\mathbf Q + v^{-1}\mathbf I) = tr(\mathbf Q) + nv^{-1}$

Sorry I missed a matrix inverse in the trace.

When $Q=I$, $v > 0 \Rightarrow z\in (0, n)$ and $v = -1 + \frac{n}{n-z}$ which is convex in $(0, n)$ as a function of $z$.
